# SQL : get count of data which have both mutations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have 2 tables `Mutations` and `Medications`.

I need the count of those members who have both mut1 and mut2 within a med name

```
SELECT 
    med.Name AS medicine, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
    Mutations mut
INNER JOIN 
    Medications med ON med.MemberId = mut.MemberId
WHERE 
    mut.Mutation IN ('mut1','mut2')
GROUP BY 
    med.Name
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT mut.Mutation) = 2
```

How to get count of those members who have both mutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is two levels of aggregation:

```
select med.name, count(*)
from (select med.name, m.memberid
      from medications med join
           mutations m
           on m.memberid = med.memberid
      where m.mutation in ('mut1', 'mut2')
      group by med.name, m.memberid
      having count(*) = 2
     ) m
group by med.name;
```

Comment: I think what you used as inner query (the one he shows) is what he has tried. Because of that, I think he wants to filter members with both mutation and with a specific med name (which should be in the where filter too)

Comment: @Gonzalo.- . . . The inner query is not exactly what the OP has in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear what count do you need, your query is actually getting the medications with both mutations...

If you want the count of your given query use a subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    med.Name AS medicine
    FROM 
        Mutations mut
    INNER JOIN 
        Medications med ON med.MemberId = mut.MemberId
    WHERE 
        mut.Mutation IN ('mut1','mut2')
    GROUP BY 
        med.Name
    HAVING 
        COUNT(DISTINCT mut.Mutation) = 2
) Q
```

If you want to separate the counts of Mut1 and mut2 use case

```
SELECT 
    med.Name AS medicine, 
    COUNT(CASE Mutation WHEN 'Mut1' THEN 1 END) AS CountMut1
    COUNT(CASE Mutation WHEN 'Mut2' THEN 1 END) AS CountMut2
FROM 
    Mutations mut
INNER JOIN 
    Medications med ON med.MemberId = mut.MemberId
WHERE 
    mut.Mutation IN ('mut1','mut2')
GROUP BY 
    med.Name
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT mut.Mutation) = 2
```